# Multiple jquery Cross Domain JSONP requests with each with the same callback

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain, jsonp

Can someone show me how to make 3 jsonp cross domain requests each with the same jsonp callback that simply gets content and writes it into the page?

I am trying to build an array of urls to loop through that i want to fire a jsonp request for each one of the urls. For each response i want to take that json object and then write the data into a section of the page. I dont care what order it is in. If i use the $.each function dont i need to take into account the scope? As i have only 1 callback function defined and i want to override the jsonp callback so it always calls the same function but that function is smart of enough to know which object was returned and to write it in to the page.

Here is my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('/server/webcontent/js/env-urls-local.js', function(data) {


                $.each(data.env.urls, function(index, url) {
                        //alert(url.path);
                        $.ajax({
                            url: url.path, 
                            dataType: 'jsonp',
                            async: false,
                            cache: false,
                            done: function(sData, textStatus, jqXHR){

                                var targetreleasediv = "." + url.target + ' td:nth-child(2)';
                                var targetdescdiv = "." + url.target + ' td:nth-child(3)';

                                //alert(targetreleasediv);
                                //alert(targetdescdiv);

                                $(targetreleasediv).html(sData.env.v);
                                $(targetdescdiv).html(sData.env.desc);
                            },
                            fail: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                                alert("Error " + jqXHR.responseText+ " error thrown is " + errorThrown + " status is " + textStatus);
                                var targetreleasediv = "." + url.target + ' td:nth-child(2)';
                                var targetdescdiv = "." + url.target + ' td:nth-child(3)';

                                //$(targetreleasediv).html("server is currently down");
                                //$(targetdescdiv).html("server is currently down");

                            }
                        });


                });


            });

    });
```

Here is the json array with the urls:

```
{
   "env":{
      "urls":[
         {
            "path":"http://server.domain.com/server/webcontent/js/evt2_server1.js",
            "target":"env2-server"
         },
         {
            "path":"http://server.domain.com/server/webcontent/js/evt2_server2.js",
            "target":"env2-server2"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here is the json string the request is returning

```
{"env":{"v":"Tag_12345","desc":"Test of purpose"}}
```

Now i when i submit the page i get the json ajax requests but neither the done or fail method gets called.

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is.  Did you try it with the one callback function and see a problem you want help solving?  If so, describe what problem you want help solving.  Otherwise, we would need to see your code and a better description of what the problem is to know how to help.

Comment: @jfriend00 I added the code above. basically i loop through the json array grab the url then fire a cross domain jsonp request. I am getting a weird behavior. I refresh the page 10 times and it works sometimes and not others. Also it works 100% of the time when the json array has only 1 url. when i add 2 it gets weird. Also, if of the request fails they all fail. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

`$.each` and `$().each` are different from a `for` loop in that for each item it loops through, the function that is ran on it is in it's own scope. You should be able to simply use the same callback in each jsonp call without worry.

Comment: The code you posted is basically what I would have provided as an example, however, i would have used `.done()` and `.fail()` instead of the depreciated `.success()` and `.error()`. That change however should not make any difference. What do you mean by "it gets weird"?

Comment: For some reason if i refresh the page 10 times it works maybe one of times. Then if i break one of the urls on purpose both will always fail when i would expect one to hit the success and one to hit the error. If i remove 1 url so there is only 1. It works 100% of the time. Very weird.

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple issues with your code:

1. reqQueue should not be an array.  The way you're using it, it should be an Object.  Once you change/fix item 2) here, I don't think you will even need reqQueue.
2. Your are defining your `.success` and `.error` handlers after you make the ajax call.  They should be defined before the ajax call.  I would suggest defining them inside the ajax data structure so they are passed right to the ajax function when it's initially made.
3. Unless you have a specific problem you're trying to solve, I think you should remove the `jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',` option from the ajax parameters.  Per the jQuery ajax doc, it's best to just let jQuery manage that function name.

Comment: Ill try those. Here is the issue with step3. I have a static javascrip t file that is hardcoded to a json string so when i let jquery do the function my javascript file i am loading is not able to append the jsonp function like a normal jsonp server would do.

Comment: I just updated the code up top. I did what you suggested however now the get the ajax calls made but it does not call the done or fail method. Suggestions?

Comment: When defining the handlers in the ajax data structure, use `success:` and `error:`, not `done:` and `fail:`.  See the [ajax doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more info.

Comment: So when i change that it gives a parse error. So i changed jsonp to json and it worked locally. however, when i deploy this it will be running a subdomain.site.com and making requests to subdomain2.site.com and subdomain3.site.com. Are those considered cross-domain? if so then i would need to make this jsonp again. I believe its givinga parse error with jsonp because my json javascript files are hardcoded with a json string after i removed jsonCallback. Because they are static js file they do not work with jsonp unless i specially tell it the callback function to call.

Comment: OK, what happens when you put the `jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback'` back?

Comment: When i add it back it works locally. When i change my urls list to the different servers i have here it then fails for a few and works for a few randomely. I get 5 working out of 10 then 8 then 2 then 7. The error i get it jsonCallback was not called and the browser javascript error is: Uncaught TypeError: Property 'jsonCallback' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function

Comment: I don't know what the issue is.  I'd have to debug a working/non-working issue to see whether you're allowed to use multiple JSONP callbacks in flight at the same time all with the same callback function name.  I don't know how jQuery handles that as that is not the usual case.

Comment: If you give me a couple working URLs where I can actually request these JSONP responses, I'll take a look in more detail.